# Why does a single loop cause a memory leak?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, garbage-collection

I'm facing with a very strange behaviour.
With this dummy code:

```
 static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        int i = 0;

        while ( true )
        {
            i++;

            String giro = "iteration " + i;

            Console.WriteLine(giro);

            Thread.Sleep(40);
        }
    }
```

Using perfom the private bytes are increasing.

[img http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2478017/memory.gif](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2478017/memory.gif)

How is it possible?

I thought GC takes care of these stuffs.

Moreover, if I compare memory behavior of this with a version in which i force GC collection every 10 iterations, the result is (for me) surprising:

[image]

The green process is the one with no GC.COllect(), and black one is the other.

Could you help me to understand the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: From 9.5 to 11 MB? You worry about that? It'll get cleaned up eventually, don't worry.

Comment: The problem is that the memory is behaving in this way since 2 hours....

Comment: @ff8mania: That's just because your program is very slow, spending most of its time sleeping.

Comment: You're right. But someone can explain me why the version with forced GC is always flat?

Comment: It is flat because it is always collected, as you force the GC.

Answer (score 9):

You're creating a bunch of strings. The GC hasn't seen fit to collect them yet. Eventually the memory graph will plateau. The GC works fine - there's no problems here :)

Answer (score 4):

The GC doesn't tidy up memory straightaway. That would be very inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Use StringBuilder instead of String and see if that doesn't solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is no leakage. Remove the Thread.Sleep(40); and wait longer, GC should kick in after a while.

Comment: Can you explain me better your reply?
Why does sleep affect GC?

Comment: @ff8mania : I said remove sleep to create String objects faster to see the effect of it on memory faster. This way you can see if it is filling memory indefinitely (a real leak) or just an artifact of VM or GC behavior. I don't think your program leaks anything.

Comment: Exactlu. It will plateu. Is not a real leak.

Answer (score 0):

Try change this:

```
String giro = "iteration " + i;
Console.WriteLine(giro);
```

to

```
Console.WriteLine("iteration " + i);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the garbage collector you can call it:

```
                        GC.Collect();
                        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

...its very expensive though...

Answer (score 0):

if you define to giro out of loop 
it will solve your issue

```
 String giro;

  while ( true )
    {
        i++;

        giro = "iteration " + i;

        Console.WriteLine(giro);

        Thread.Sleep(40);
    }
```